# Java - read an array of bytes from an InputStream until a certain character

Tags: java, inputstream

i need to read an Base64 encoded array of bytes from an inputstream.

I have to stop reading when I reach a \n character in the decoded string, i cannot find an efficient way to do this.

Now i ended with something like this but it does not work as intended because it's too easy it catches an exception and messes all up...

```
byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
    byte results[] = new byte[2048];
    String totalResult = null;
    try {
        int bytes_read = is.read(buffer);
        while (buffer[bytes_read - 1] != '\n') {
            bytes_read = is.read(buffer);
            String app = new String(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
            totalResult += app;

        }
        String response = Base64.getDecoder().decode(totalResult).toString();
```

Any idea? The input Stream does not close, so i need to get data from it and separated by '\n'

Comment: Is `is` different from `this.is`?

Comment: maybe not the best design...do this for fun but for real project think about a better design

Comment: @AndyTurner it was a typo...

Comment: @Multithreader this was the best i could get... unlucky i do not manage the input stream, i just need to read it...

Comment: @besmart well, it could be an important difference. Why do you read again without appending to `totalResult`?

Comment: If you're just trying to read up to a `\n`, why not just use `totalResult = new BufferedReader(is).readLine()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, consider using (for example) `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream` from the [Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) project and a `BufferedReader` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--)) to wrap your `InputStream` like so:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new Base64InputStream(is)))) {
    String response = reader.readLine();
    ...
}
```

Notes:

- Try with resources will automatically close the reader when you're done.
- The Base64InputStream will decode Base64 encoded characters on the fly
- `BufferedReader.readLine()`considers `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n` to be line separators for the purpose of determining the end of a line.
- I am sure other libraries exist that will facilitate the on-the-fly decoding, or you could write a simple InputStreamWrapper yourself.

Comment: it looks a very good solution, but i don't know why it does not read anything and just sometimes and empty string...

Comment: If the string is empty and there is no Exception (which you might want to catch at the end of the try), it would indicate that the first character in the stream was actually a new line (NL). To confirm this you could subclass `Base64InputStream` and make it print each byte sequence it encounters before it converts. Do you have any control over the source of the incoming data? Is it a live stream? Are there reasons why it may produce an NL by design? Is it possible that the stream can contain double NLs (in which case first read is as expected, but a second read would start with NL)?